# How to control the size of images and graphics?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been having trouble arranging graphic elements correctly. Here's an example:

```
im1 = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/London_2010_Tower_Bridge.jpg"];
GraphicsRow[{im1, ImageAdd[im1, Graphics[Disk[]]], Graphics[Disk[]]}]
```

[image: example of problems]

The circles are both specified in the same way, but show at different scales, so the diagram that attempts to show how it works isn't very satisfactory. Obviously one is scaled to match the image, but I can't see why they don't appear the same size. `Row` is similar to `GraphicsRow` but gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem occurs because in the display, the disk used in the mask has a diameter equal to the height of the image, whereas the stand-alone disk has a diameter equal to the width of the image. You can correct this by specifying the size of the disk explicitly.

```
im1 = Import[
   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/London_2010_\
Tower_Bridge.jpg"];
disk = Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@im1];
GraphicsRow[{im1, ImageAdd[im1, disk], disk}, Spacings -> 0, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to wrap the images in a `Pane` with automatic width and fixed height, e.g.

```
Row[Pane[#, {Automatic, 200}] & /@ 
 {im1, ImageAdd[im1, Graphics[Disk[]]], Graphics[Disk[]]}]
```

[image: scaled to have the dame height]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Pane...!

Comment: This looks so immaculate!

Answer (score 5):

There is padding around the images and none around the black disk. By knowing the aspect ratio of the imported image (obtained from ImageDimensions), and by setting a specific size for GraphicsRow and for the the black disk, you can control the appearance:

```
GraphicsRow[{im1, ImageAdd[im1, Graphics[Disk[]]], 
  Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 90, ImagePadding -> 15]}, 
 ImageSize -> 360, Spacings -> 0]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, nice to see you here. Welcome to Stack Overflow!